# DbContext.SaveChanges() method not committing to SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

This is my code, which is part of an ASP.NET MVC controller Action (triggered with a button click)

```
using(var context = new EDIDEVEntities())
{
    var result = from b in context.DOWNLOAD_ORDER_HEADER.Where(b => csgList.Contains(b.PRO_NUM_ALPHA)) select b;

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        item.STATUS = "Assigned";
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It doesn't throw any error, but records in the database aren't updated.

I tried using this line:

```
context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

before the foreach loop, but it throws an error which says

> The entity type DbQuery`1 is not part of the model for the current context

I understand that the actual lines of code should be something like:

```
DOWNLOAD_ORDER_HEADER doh;
context.Entry(doh).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But I need to update one field of the DOWNLOAD_ORDER_HEADER table only for rows returned by my LINQ query. How can I do this?

Comment: `context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;` inside the loop

Comment: Should work fine even without manually modifying the state of the entity as the update is performed in the same context itself. Are you getting expected output in the `result` ?

Comment: You could try adding a breakpoint at/before the foreach line to make sure `result` is not empty. Otherwise I don't see how the changes are not saved.

Comment: It is not needed to change the State to modified. Assigning a new value already changes this value. Debugging help: You can see the state in the debugger by checking the state after your assignment. Are you sure your result is not empty? Use: Result.Any(). Are you sure your assignment is a change? Check the value of item before your assignment. Are you sure nothing is save: check the return value of SaveChanges()

Comment: I checked everything. context.SaveChanges() returns a value of 3 (which matches the number of rows supposed to be updated in the database. But when I query the database, the changes aren't there. It's just so strange.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the context.Entry(item).State if you are actually modifying the item.STATUS, if the item.STATUS already equals "Assigned", obviously Entity Framework will not do an update as there are no changes.

For testing, this is the correct changing of the Entity State, you need to set the State of each item in your results for loop:

```
var result = from b in context.DOWNLOAD_ORDER_HEADER.Where(b => csgList.Contains(b.PRO_NUM_ALPHA)) select b;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    item.STATUS = "Assigned";
    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Why Entity Framework is not automatically setting the State of each DOWNLOAD_ORDER_HEADER Entity to Modified is strange, if the item.STATUS is something other then "Assigned" then the context.SaveChanges(); after the for loop should perform an update to the database.

In the mean time, manually doing `context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;` for each item in your for loop will prove or not prove that your database is getting updated.

Do you have this code wrapped in a try catch block and there actually is an exception being thrown and it is possibly being handled?

Comment: I tried it, and context.SaveChanges() returns a value of 3 (which matches the number of rows supposed to be updated in the database. But when I query the database, the changes aren't there.

Comment: Perhaps you are querying the wrong database and you aren't realizing it?

Comment: @doodles Perhaps there is something wrong with your database query

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code hope this will help you.

context."YOUR DATABASE TABLE".AddObject(result);
 context.SaveChanges();

Comment: His objects are **already** part of the context, and he's just updating them - there's absolutely **no need** to use `.AddObject` - quite the contrary, this will result **in an error** (since that object **already is** part of the context!)

Comment: Please remove this answer, it is incorrect, the objects are already part of the context, the context query is what gives the for each entities to iterate over